# Conditional query in MySQL involving 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I've 2 tables `TABLE 1` and `TABLE 2` with following definition:

```
SUB-ID  varchar(25)
CLICKS  int(5)
ACTIONS int(4)
EARNINGS    varchar(10)
EPC varchar(5)
```

I'm running the following query involving both the tables:

```
SELECT t1.CLICKS, t1.ACTIONS, t1.EARNINGS AS CurrentWeekEarnings
     , t2.EARNINGS AS PastWeekEarnings 
FROM `TABLE 1` AS t1, `TABLE 2` AS t2 
WHERE t1.`SUB-ID` = '" . $_POST['subId'] . "' 
  AND t2.`SUB-ID` = t1.`SUB-ID`
```

For cases where a given subId is present in both the tables, the query works fine but in some case the given subId is present in `TABLE 1` but not in `TABLE 2` and the query results 0 rows.

Now, I am new to MySQL and I don't have any experience with conditional queries in MySQL at all.

I do have an idea that if I could specify a condition where the given subId is not present in `TABLE 2`, a different query is executed retrieving only the first 3 columns i.e., CLICKS, ACTIONS and EARNINGS from `TABLE 1` and setting the value of PastWeekEarnings to $0.

Please tell me how do I achieve this i.e., how do I conditionally switch between both the queries as well as setting the value of PastWeekEarnings to $0 when the subId is not present in `TABLE 2`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider doing a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` like

```
SELECT t1.CLICKS, 
t1.ACTIONS, 
t1.EARNINGS AS CurrentWeekEarnings,
t2.EARNINGS AS PastWeekEarnings 
FROM `TABLE 1` t1 LEFT JOIN `TABLE 2` t2 
ON t2.`SUB-ID` = t1.`SUB-ID`
WHERE t1.`SUB-ID` = '" . $_POST['subId'] . "';
```